# Android Bluetooth Chat Example Application Singleton Class NullPointerException

Tags: android, bluetooth, singleton, broadcastreceiver

I modified Bluetooth chat example in order to make it send the sms text through BT to another device on receiving it.I'm getting NullPointerException when i'm trying to access the SendMessage method of Application class from the receiver.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static MainActivity mThis;


    // Layout Views
    private TextView mNotificationView;

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");

        // Set up the window layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get local Bluetooth adapter
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "++ ON START ++");

        // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
        // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        // Otherwise, setup the chat session
        } else {
            if (mChatService == null) setupChat();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "+ ON RESUME +");

        // Performing this check in onResume() covers the case in which BT was
        // not enabled during onStart(), so we were paused to enable it...
        // onResume() will be called when ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE activity returns.
        if (mChatService != null) {
            // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
            if (mChatService.getState() == BTService.STATE_NONE) {
              // Start the Bluetooth chat services
              mChatService.start();
            }
        }
    }

   private void setupChat() {

       mNotificationView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notification);

        mChatService = new BTService(this, mHandler);
//
//        // Initialize the buffer for outgoing messages
       mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
   }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "- ON PAUSE -");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "-- ON STOP ---");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Stop the Bluetooth chat services
        if (mChatService != null) mChatService.stop();
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "--- ON DESTROY ---");
    }



    // The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                case BTService.STATE_CONNECTED:
//                    setStatus(getString(R.string.title_connected_to, mConnectedDeviceName));
//                    mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                    break;
                case BTService.STATE_CONNECTING:
//                    setStatus(R.string.title_connecting);
                    break;
                case BTService.STATE_LISTEN:
                case BTService.STATE_NONE:
//                    setStatus(R.string.title_not_connected);
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the buffer
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                mNotificationView.setText(writeMessage);
               // mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
//                mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + readMessage);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                // save the connected device's name
                mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "
                               + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST),
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult " + resultCode);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                connectDevice(data, true);
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                connectDevice(data, false);
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session
//                setupChat();
            } else {
                // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occurred
                Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private void connectDevice(Intent data, boolean secure) {

        String address = "00:15:FF:F3:C6:8A";

        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        mChatService.connect(device, true);
    }
}
```

**BTService.java**

```
public class BTService {

    // Unique UUID for this application
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID
            .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // Member fields
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private AcceptThread mSecureAcceptThread;
    private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private int mState;

    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

    public BTService(Context context, Handler handler) {
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mState = STATE_NONE;
        mHandler = handler;
    }


    private synchronized void setState(int state) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
        mState = state;

        // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
        mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
    }


    public synchronized int getState() {
        return mState;
    }


    public synchronized void start() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "start");

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        setState(STATE_LISTEN);

        // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
        if (mSecureAcceptThread == null) {
            mSecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(true);
            mSecureAcceptThread.start();
        }
        if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(false);
            mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
        }
    }


    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        // Start the thread to connect with the given device
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, secure);
        mConnectThread.start();
        setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
     * @param socket  The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
     * @param device  The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
     */
    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice
            device, final String socketType) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connected, Socket Type:" + socketType);

        // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
        if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
            mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
            mSecureAcceptThread = null;
        }
        if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
            mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket, socketType);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MainActivity.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }

    /**
     * Stop all threads
     */
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "stop");

        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
            mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
            mSecureAcceptThread = null;
        }

        if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
            mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
        }
        setState(STATE_NONE);
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     * @param out The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionFailed() {
        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MainActivity.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        // Start the service over to restart listening mode
        BTService.this.start();
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionLost() {
        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MainActivity.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        // Start the service over to restart listening mode
        BTService.this.start();
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
     * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
     * (or until cancelled).
     */
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
        private String mSocketType;

        public AcceptThread(boolean secure) {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
            mSocketType = secure ? "Secure":"Insecure";

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {
                if (secure) {
                    tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE,
                        MY_UUID);
                } else {
                    tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                            NAME_INSECURE, MY_UUID);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "listen() failed", e);
            }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType +
                    "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
            setName("AcceptThread" + mSocketType);

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
            while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                try {
                    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                    // successful connection or an exception
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "accept() failed", e);
                    break;
                }

                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    synchronized (BTService.this) {
                        switch (mState) {
                        case STATE_LISTEN:
                        case STATE_CONNECTING:
                            // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                            connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice(),
                                    mSocketType);
                            break;
                        case STATE_NONE:
                        case STATE_CONNECTED:
                            // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                               Log.d(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (D) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread, socket Type: " + mSocketType);

        }

        public void cancel() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "cancel " + this);
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "close() of server failed", e);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
     * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
     * succeeds or fails.
     */
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
        private String mSocketType;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
            mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                if (secure) {
                    tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                            MY_UUID);
                } else {
                    tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                            MY_UUID);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "create() failed", e);
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:" + mSocketType);
            setName("ConnectThread" + mSocketType);

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "unable to close() " + mSocketType +
                            " socket during connection failure", e2);
                }
                connectionFailed();
                return;
            }

            // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
            synchronized (BTService.this) {
                mConnectThread = null;
            }

            // Start the connected thread
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice, mSocketType);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.d(TAG, "close() of connect " + mSocketType + " socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
     * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
     */
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.d(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                    BTService.this.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Write to the connected OutStream.
         * @param buffer  The bytes to write
         */
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "INSIDE WRITE METHOD");
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);

                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.d(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.d(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**IncomingCallsSMSReceiver.java**

```
public class IncomingCallsSMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    String prestate, callerno;
    private String SENDTAG;
    private String SENDMESSAGE;
    SMSBT myApp;
    private String TAG = "SMSRECEIVER";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Bundle extras = arg1.getExtras();

        if (arg1.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
            Log.i("i", "New Message");

            if (extras != null) {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage
                            .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage
                            .getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum
                            + "; message: " + message);

                    SENDTAG = "S";
                    SENDMESSAGE = "New SMS :: From :: " + senderNum + " :: "
                            + message;

                    try {

                        SMSBT.getInstance().sendMessage(SENDTAG, SENDMESSAGE);
                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                SENDTAG + SENDMESSAGE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (MainActivity.mThis != null) {
                        ((TextView) MainActivity.mThis
                                .findViewById(R.id.notification))
                                .setText(SENDTAG + " " + SENDMESSAGE);
                    } else {
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**SMSBT.java**

```
public class SMSBT extends Application {

    private StringBuffer mOutStringBuffer;
    private String TAG = "ABLUETOOTH";

    private static SMSBT singleton;

    private BTService btService;

    // Returns the application instance
    public static SMSBT getInstance() {
        if (singleton == null) {
            singleton = new SMSBT();

        }
        return singleton;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    void sendMessage(String sendTAG, String sendMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Hooooooorayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy INSIDE send message send message send message send message");
//
//      if (btService != null) {
//          // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't
//          // started already
//          if (btService.getState() == BTService.STATE_NONE) {
//              // Start the Bluetooth chat services
//              btService.start();
//
//          } else if (btService.getState() == BTService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                if (sendMessage.length() > 0) {
                    // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService
                    // to write
                    byte[] send = (sendTAG + sendMessage).getBytes();
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "TRY TRY TRY BLOCK BLOCK BLOCK");
                        btService.write(send);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Transferred to SmartBand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text
                    // field
                    mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
                    if (MainActivity.mThis != null) {
                        ((TextView) MainActivity.mThis
                                .findViewById(R.id.notification))
                                .setText(sendMessage);
                    } else {
                        Log.i("i", " GGGGGGGOT A NULLLLLLLLLLLL");
                    }
                }
            }
    //  }
//  }
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
TRY TRY TRY BLOCK BLOCK BLOCK
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.practice.abluetooth.SMSBT.sendMessage(SMSBT.java:50)
at com.practice.abluetooth.IncomingCallsSMSReceiver.onReceive(IncomingCallsSMSReceiver.java:52)
.
.
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.practice.abluetooth.SMSBT.sendMessage(SMSBT.java:61)
    at com.practice.abluetooth.IncomingCallsSMSReceiver.onReceive(IncomingCallsSMSReceiver.java:52)
```

Awaiting for help.

Comment: why have you commented if (btService != null) it is giving exception because btService  is not initialized.